# how to apply asof join on partitioned tables in kdb

Tags: kdb

I need to run asof join on few years data of trade and quote tables which are partitioned.
When I read through - https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/aj/ 
Above url states that -

```
"If further where constraints are used, the columns will be copied instead of mapped into memory, slowing down the join."
```

How can I use asof join over partitioned database with date and other constraints without impacting performance or memory.

```
Eg: aj[`sym`time;select from trade where date>2019.01.01, app=`abc; select from quote where date>2019.01.01]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do `date=` and run for `each/peach` date rather than doing `date>`, i.e.

```
raze{aj[`sym`time;select from trade where date=x, app=`abc;select from quote where date=x]}peach 2019.01.01 2019.01.02 2019.01.03
```

It's usually acceptable to have an additional filter on trade but probably only if that column `app` has a parted attribute. You can't have any filters on quote or performance tanks.

Note that with this approach you can't join prevailing data from previous day onto the next day but in most cases you wouldn't want/need to do that anyway

Comment: Thanks for the answer Terry. But if we want to join trade and quotes data not on day basis but for a whole year, in that case will asof join not able to join the data because of memory issues and can this usecase be solved in some other way?

Comment: To do a whole year you run the function for each/peach date in that whole year. You will naturally hit memory issues if you're trying to hold a years worth of data in memory so in that case you can write to disk immediately after the join rather than trying to store it all in memory. ```{(`$":db/",string[x],"/ajTrades/") set .Q.en[`:db]aj[`sym`time;select from trade where date=x, app=`abc;select from quote where date=x]}peach 2019.01.01 2019.01.02 2019.01.03```